# Using masks or clip to create complex corners on flexible height & width sidebar

Tags: css, mask, clip-path

I have a sidebar with a textured background that needs to be flexible both vertically and horizontally.

Each of the corners has a clip/mask and I would like to figure out how to do this using css. Here's an example of the corner pattern, top left and bottom right:

- [image: Top left]
- [image: Bottom Right]

I can figure out the basics of a clip pattern for the origin corner (starting from 0,0) but is it possible to do the other corners without knowing the height or width beforehand?

Comment: the corner are solid color ? transparent, so we see what behind ?

Comment: the corners are transparent

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you're asking for, since the approach isn't using clip-path, but you could try border-image with a 9 patch approach as seen here: https://codepen.io/dehnavi/pen/MebRbj